select the correct Visual Studio Version for setuptools
I do want to compile a a library in C++ for Python. Running python setup.py install --user returns the following warning
cl: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 62: invalid start byte
warnings.warn(f'Error checking compiler version for {compiler}: {error}')

and later I get the error (Due to CUDA 10.2):
fatal error C1189: #error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions between 2015 and 2019 (inclusive) are supported!

running cl or vswhere result in a command cannot be found error
Adding vswhere and cl to the PATH result in:
cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++-Compiler Version 19.16.27045 for x64

vswhere now finds Visual Studio 2017 and 2022
However: MSVC.py in setuptools seem to only look for the latest version of VS Studio (The command seems to be vswhere -latest -prerelease -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 -property installationPath -products *  which results in the unsupported 2022 version.
Is there any way to specify the version for setuptools to use? Alternatively: Can I temporarily remove Visual Studio 2022 from vswhere?
Any suggestions?
